# Image Sprite in TextBox Background

Tags: input, background, background-image, css-sprites, shorthand

I want to display an image in the background of a input text-box.The image should be placed at the right most center part of the input text-box.It can be done easily by the following code:

```
    <input type="text" class="card" size=20 />
```

The css will be:

```
    .card{
     background:url('image.png') no-repeat right center;
       }
```

The problem i am facing is the image is a sprite and consists of 3 images.I want to display the one at background position -34px 0 and its width is 23px;

How to specify both background position and size with css?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot clip the background in CSS if the sprite is tight, other option would be to add a span next to the input box and set the background to the sprite and the height and width correctly, then use the background position to get the correct image, once this is done you can then position the span using a minus left value to pull it to the left over the text box, hope this helps :)

```
<div style="position:relative; display:inline-block;">
  <input type="text" /><span style="position:absolute; right:0px; background:#FF0000">O</span>
</div>
```

Comment: I am making this page for a mobile websites.Will the span positioning handle on all the screen sizes?

Comment: Yes, if your wrapper is correctly positioned, I have added a test for you, be aware of the display attribute in the `<div>` IE would require `display:inline` instead